# Where is tools.jar located?

Tags: java, tools.jar

Running `CentOS 6`, `Java 1.7.0_25 OpenJDK`

Upon installing the `RPM` I saw it say

```
Unpacking JAR files...
rt.jar
jsee.jar
charsets.jar
>tools.jar
```

Where is `tools.jar` located? I checked `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64`

No where to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, I could find it at `\jdk1.7.0\lib`. You can find java directory structure [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)

Answer (score 32):

Not sure what rpm you used, but if you install from yum repo, you should install `java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` in addition to `java-1.7.0-openjdk`.

Then you will find `tools.jar` in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.xx.x86_64/lib` directory.

Comment: Just putting another emphasis on installing `openjdk-devel` in addition to `openjdk`. Tried and tested on Amazon Linux.

Comment: This solved my issue with apache-axis. I was getting this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No compiler found in your classpath!  (you may need to add 'tools.jar')

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, you can use `locate tools.jar` to find where the file is.

Typically, it should be in the lib/ directory of your jvm. On Ubuntu/Debian, it is located in directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-xxxxx/lib/tools.jar`.

For example, with openjdk 7, on amd64, I'll find it under /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar.

I have no installation to check it, but I think that the directory structure is the same under CentOS (cf. https://serverfault.com/questions/50883/what-is-the-value-of-java-home-for-centos)

Comment: This may be obvious, but out-of-the-box Ubuntu 16.04 did not have `/usr/lib/jvm/java-*/lib/tools.jar` until I ran `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` (and `locate` won't work until you run `sudo updatedb`)

Answer (score 6):

Linux Centos 6,

you can use **sudo find / -name "tools.jar"** command to find the file location.

tools.jar is normally located under /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0.70.x86_64/lib/tools.jar

tools.jar is not in JRE.

My case, tools.jar file is generated only after installing java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.

**sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel**

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

No,it should be in  in `Lib` folder

[JDK and JRE File Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)

> c:\jdkx.x.x\lib
>
> Files used by the development tools. **These include  tools.jar**, which contains non-core classes for support of the tools and utilities in the JDK. Also includes dt.jar, the DesignTime archive of BeanInfo files that tell interactive development environments (IDE's) how to display the Java components and how to let the developer customize them for an application.